# Modbus TCP Python Server not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am trying to use asynchronous `modbus` server based to stream multiple values of data but I simply see zeros. Please help. My code is based on

https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous-server.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
# Pymodbus Asynchronous Server Example
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#----

#The asynchronous server is a high performance implementation using the
#twisted library as its backend.  This allows it to scale to many #thousands
#of nodes which can be helpful for testing monitoring software.
'''
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# import the various server implementations
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.server.async import StartUdpServer
from pymodbus.server.async import StartSerialServer

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# configure the service logging
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# initialize your data store
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# The datastores only respond to the addresses that they are initialized to.
# Therefore, if you initialize a DataBlock to addresses of 0x00 to 0xFF, a
# request to 0x100 will respond with an invalid address exception. This is
# because many devices exhibit this kind of behavior (but not all)::
#
#     block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, \[0\]*0xff)
#
# Continuing, you can choose to use a sequential or a sparse DataBlock #in
# your data context.  The difference is that the sequential has no gaps #in
# the data while the sparse can. Once again, there are devices that #exhibit
# both forms of behavior::
#
#     block = ModbusSparseDataBlock({0x00: 0, 0x05: 1})
#     block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, \[0\]*5)
#
# Alternately, you can use the factory methods to initialize the #DataBlocks
# or simply do not pass them to have them initialized to 0x00 on the #full
# address range::
#
#     store = ModbusSlaveContext(di =   #ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create())
#     store = ModbusSlaveContext()
#
# Finally, you are allowed to use the same DataBlock reference for  #every
# table or you you may use a seperate DataBlock for each table. This #depends
# if you would like functions to be able to access and modify the same #data
# or not::
#
#     block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, \[0\]*0xff)
#     store = ModbusSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block,ir=block)
#
# The server then makes use of a server context that allows the server #to
# respond with different slave contexts for different unit ids. By #default
# it will return the same context for every unit id supplied (broadcast
# mode). However, this can be overloaded by setting the single flag to #False
# and then supplying a dictionary of unit id to context mapping::
#
#     slaves  = {
#         0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(...),
#         0x02: ModbusSlaveContext(...),
#         0x03: ModbusSlaveContext(...),
#     }
#     context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slaves, single=False)
#
# The slave context can also be initialized in zero_mode which means #that a
# request to address(0-7) will map to the address (0-7). The default is
# False which is based on section 4.4 of the specification, so address(0-7)
# will map to (1-8)::
#
#     store = ModbusSlaveContext(..., zero_mode=True)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(5, \[15\]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(6, \[16\]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(7, \[17\]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(8, \[18\]*100))
#context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

slaves = {
    0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(1, \[15\]*100),
    0x02: ModbusSlaveContext(2, \[16\]*100),
    0x03: ModbusSlaveContext(3, \[17\]*100),
    0x04: ModbusSlaveContext(4, \[15\]*100),
    0x05: ModbusSlaveContext(5, \[16\]*100),
    0x06: ModbusSlaveContext(6, \[17\]*100),
}
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slaves, single=False)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# initialize the server information
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# If you don't set this or any fields, they are defaulted to empty strings.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName  = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl   = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName   = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# run the server you want
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhost", 502))
#StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhost", 5020))
#StartUdpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhost", 502))
#StartSerialServer(context, identity=identity, port='/dev/pts/3', framer=ModbusRtuFramer)
#StartSerialServer(context, identity=identity, port='/dev/pts/3', framer=ModbusAsciiFramer)
```

[image: img]

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could work with? That will make it more likely you'll get a high quality answer to your question.